# How to find data on dupes in SP

Tags: support, data-explorer

Per [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267092/are-questions-about-how-to-code-on-the-so-data-explorer-on-topic-for-so#267096), I believe this question is on-topic for this site.

I am attempting to find reputation data on duplicates on Stack Overflow using the Data Explorer.  What I want out of this query:

- Most rep gained from asking a dupe
- Most rep gained from answering a dupe
- Average rep gained from asking a dupe
- Average rep gained from answering a dupe
- Average rep rate from dupes on the site per unit time

I have zero experience with SQL, so I figured I'd try to reason out what to do from other queries and start with baby steps, find all positive scoring dupes.  [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site) is the one I've been pulling from the most.  Based on that, I made a few modifications to get this:

```sql
set nocount on 

declare @DupeInfo table (PostId int, Score int) 

insert @DupeInfo
select
    PostId, 
    Score
from Posts
group by PostId

set nocount off


select top 10 p.id as [Post Link] , up from @DupeInfo 
join Posts p on PostId = p.Id
where Score > 0 and p.CommunityOwnedDate is null and  not p.ClosedDate is null
order by Score desc
```

I'm hung up on how to get only duplicates.  I modified the `where` condition at the end to be `not p.ClosedDate`, but this should get me all closed posts, not only dupes.  I can see `CloseReasonTypes` `ID` of `1` or `101` corresponds to dupes, but how do I apply this?

Comment: If you're not restricted to Data Explorer, this is much easier if you just use the [built-in site search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=duplicate%3a1) (search for `duplicate:1` then switch to the votes tab).

Comment: That works for this specific query, but I would like to try to understand Data Explorer so that I can use it in the future

Comment: Well there's a couple things to clarify. 1. In your declaration at the top, you're trying to select Score from the Votes table, which doesn't exist. I'm really not sure what exactly you're doing up there at all, because you appear to be selecting all uvotes in the entire database and grouping them by post. Each post in the database already has a cached Score with it, so all of that work seems unnecessary. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. p.CommunityOwnedDate being null will exclude all community wiki posts from the query, is that something you want to do?

Comment: To your second question, yes, to your first, I'll update to provide more clarity

Comment: @animuson, updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific reason why you wanted to use a stored procedure for this because I have a solution that uses Common Table Expressions and deliver close to what you ask.

This is the query [Rep gained by asking a duplicate](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/213938/rep-gained-by-asking-a-duplicate) that shows the ranking for reputation gained per duplicate question, dulicate answer and a total of the two:

```
with questions as(
select p.owneruserid
     , sum(
        case v.voteTypeId
          when 2 then  5 -- upmod
          when 3 then -2 -- downmod
          else case 
               when p.acceptedanswerid <> null  then 2
               else 0
               end
        end
       ) as QuestionReputation
from posts p 
inner join postlinks pl on pl.postid = p.id 
left outer join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where pl.linktypeid = 3  -- duplicate
and p.communityowneddate is null
and p.owneruserid is not null
group by p.owneruserid
)
, answers as (
select p.owneruserid
     , sum(
        case v.voteTypeId
          when 1 then 15 -- accepted
          when 2 then 10 -- upmod
          when 3 then -2 -- downmod
          else 0
        end
       ) as AnswerReputation
from posts p
inner join posts q on p.parentid = q.id 
                  and q.posttypeid = 1 
inner join postlinks pl on pl.postid = q.id 
left outer join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where pl.linktypeid = 3  -- duplicate
and p.posttypeid = 2 -- answer
and q.communityowneddate is null
and p.communityowneddate is null
and p.owneruserid is not null
and q.owneruserid is not null
group by p.owneruserid
)
, qusr as (
select top 5000 
       row_number() over (order by q.questionreputation desc) as rowid
     , q.owneruserid
     , q.questionreputation
from questions q 
order by q.questionreputation desc
)
, ausr as (
select top 5000 
      row_number() over (order by a.answerreputation desc) as rowid
     , a.owneruserid
     , a.answerreputation
from
answers a  
order by a.answerreputation desc
)
, totusr as (
select top 5000 
       row_number() over (order by coalesce(q.questionreputation,0) +  coalesce(a.answerreputation,0) desc) as rowid
     , coalesce(q.owneruserid,a.owneruserid) as owneruserid
     , coalesce(q.questionreputation,0) +  coalesce(a.answerreputation,0) as tot
from users u
left outer join questions q on q.owneruserid = u.id
left outer join answers a on a.owneruserid = u.id
where (q.owneruserid is not null or a.owneruserid is not null)
order by coalesce(q.questionreputation,0) +  coalesce(a.answerreputation,0) desc
)
select top 5000  
       q.rowid as [Rank]
     , q.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , q.questionreputation as [Q Rep]
     , a.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , a.answerreputation as [A Rep]
     , t.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , t.tot as [Tot Rep]
from qusr q 
inner join ausr a on a.rowid = q.rowid
inner join totusr t on t.rowid = q.rowid
order by q.rowid
```

#### How does this work

The postlinks holds the links between duplicate posts. The records with a LinkTypeId of 3 indicate a duplicate. By joining with the posts table you get all questions that are dulicates.

The votes table holds upvotes/downvotes (and accepts for answers). A sum based on the Votetypeid gives you the repuatation gained.

After that the row_number() function gives you the rank in the result. The last query joins all results based on rank.

#### What is still missing?

The *average of the reputation* gained. I leave that as an exercise for the reader. Be carefull which rows you count though...

I have no idea how *average reputation rate on the site  per unit time* would look like but you can get that by aggregating per date from the Votes table. That would require a complete new query and I only do one query per question.

Comment: This is brilliant! Quick question: If I want to see all the dupes (not just the top 5000), I would fork the query and get rid of all the ```select top 5000``` lines, correct?

Comment: You could try that but it might time-out... Votes and Posts are tables with a lot of rows...